# Using Biblatex with utf8x

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, unicode

I'm trying to write a thesis proposal which includes a sentence in Hebrew.

I use the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{culmus}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}

\addbibresource{Bib.bib}

\begin{document}


\L{\huge{hello hello}}
\end{spacing}

\medskip
\Large{שלום}

\section{References:}}
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

Im getting the following error:

```
Incompatible package 'ucs'. See the biblatex package.
```

I read that there is a problem using utf8x with biblatex and that it should be used as utf8.

However if I use utf8 i'm not able to write a sentence in Hebrew.

Another thing I tried is as following by using XeLatex:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{Bib.bib}
\begin{document}

\section{hello}
{\bfseries hello:}

Hebrew: מה הבעיה?

\medskip
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

However still error.

Is there a solution to be able to write in Hebrew and to insert bib file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use ucs. So either you switch to an unicode engine line xelatex or lualatex. Or you declare the missing unicode chars for utf8 like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{culmus}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}

\pdfmapfile{=culmus.map}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{05E9}{\hebshin}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{05DC}{\heblamed}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{05D5}{\hebvav}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{05DD}{\hebfinalmem}
% and more 

\begin{document}


\Large{שלום}


\end{document}
```

[image]

You can find the command names in he8enc.def.

Comment: I added another thing that I tried without utf8x and used XeLatex however it also not working.

Comment: How to get it working with xelatex/lualatex is quite a different question. Search the site for answers, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434549/minimal-babel-and-lualatex-hebrew-bidi-example