# Multi-file latex project, with a title page in hebrew

Tags: babel, standalone, hebrew, import, subfiles

I have a large LaTeX project (my thesis) with a main TeX file (`main.tex`) and many subfiles contained in their own sub-directory. All are interrelated with the `subfiles` package.

Now I want to add a title page to appear on the first page of the compiled pdf file, with hebrew text: To include the thesis title, author name and institution name.

The preponderance of the project is best compiled with `pdfLatex`, and therefore I wish to stick with this one and not change to `XeLaTeX`.

I successfully compiled a `.tex` file that contains hebrew AND english letters (`titlepage.tex`).

I want `titlepage.tex` to appear first, and after it all the series of `chapter0*.tex` files.

Now comes the question - how to compile the project properly?

I tried to import the `standalone` and `import` packages to `main.tex`:

```
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}
```

and then call for `titlepage.tex` right after `\begin{document}`:
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}
\begin{docment}
\import{./}{titlepage}
\end{document}

But nothing compiled - a multitude of errors concerning the `standalone.sty` file.

Any help?

The hierarchical file structure is as follows:

```
root folder
├main.tex
├titlepage.tex
└───figures
| │ figure01
│ │ figure02
│ │ figure03
└───subfiles
| │ chapter01
| │ chapter02
| │ chapter03
```

The `main.tex` file structure:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book} % Tufte-book format
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Bibliography
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{subfiles} % Best loaded last in the preamble
%%% Document %%%
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\subfile{subfiles/chapter01}

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\subfile{subfiles/chapter02}

\chapter{Chapter 3}
\subfile{subfiles/chapter03}
\end{document}
```

The `chpater0*.tex` files has just the same document preamble as `main.tex`.

The Hebrew language file, to be used as a title page:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
%\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % utf8x for hebrew letters
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}

\begin{document}
כיתוב בעברית.
\selectlanguage{english}
English text.
\end{document}
```

Note: I compile the the project in overleaf.

Comment: In `titlepage.tex` I'd remove everything up to and including `\begin{document}` as well as `\end{document}`, and include the file from `main.tex` using `\input{titlepage}`. No `standalone` and `import` needed (any packages and definitions that are needed in the title page, put them into the preamble). There is probably no need to compile the titlepage separately. If there is, then use `\subfile` to load the titlepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Overleaf also with multiple subfiles. I use the command `\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}` to import the preamble of the main into the subfiles. Besides `\selectlanguage` should be used inside the document I think.

Here is my an example inspired by your MWE that worked for me :

`main.tex` :

```
\documentclass{tufte-book} % Tufte-book format
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english, hebrew]{babel}
\usepackage{subfiles} % Best loaded last in the preamble

\newcommand{\onlyinsubfile}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\notinsubfile}[1]{}

%%% Document %%%
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\onlyinsubfile}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\notinsubfile}[1]{#1}

\subfile{titlepage}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\subfile{subfiles/chapter0}

\end{document}
```

`titlepage.tex`

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
כיתוב בעברית.
\selectlanguage{english}
English text.
\end{document}
```

The functions `\onlyinsubfile` and `\notinsubfile` can be used in the subfiles and allow you to execute commands depending if you are trying to compile the standalone subfile or the whole document.

Finally for managing biblatex with hebrew caracter look at this answer [Using Biblatex with utf8x](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446322/using-biblatex-with-utf8x)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! But, I now notice that there is a problem with the `figure` environment: I get the following errors: Missing \endcsname inserted; Use of \m@^_ doesn't match its definition; Extra \endcsname. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I am not sure how this could be related to the use of subfiles... Could you post a MWE ? Maybe in another question and post the link in comment. I will have a look

Comment: Good idea. The new answer I posted can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/587646/).