# figure environment isn't compiling with babel and hebrew in pdflatex

Tags: floats, babel, input-encodings, font-encodings, hebrew

I have a project that is written both in Hebrew and in English, which is compiled with `pdfLatex` on Overleaf. Since this compiler is not a Unicode engine, one has to declare the Hebrew letters explicitly (as I learned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446328)). This is the reason for the `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{---}{\heb---}` commands in the preamble below.

It works fine, up until the moment I wanted to insert an image to my document, with a `figure` environment.

The `main.tex` and `chapter01.tex` files are given below, with the hierarchical file structure:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book} % Tufte-book format
% Encoding stuff
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english, hebrew]{babel}


%% Herbew letters declarations %%
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{05D0}{\hebalef}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{05D1}{\hebbet}
% and so on until
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{05EA}{\hebtav}

\usepackage{subfiles} % Best loaded last in the preamble. Used to break the content of the project into smaller files

\begin{document}
\subfile{subfiles/chapter01}
\subfile{subfiles/chapter02}
\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
כיתוב בעברית.
\selectlanguage{english}
Some english text, and this is a figure:
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{images/figure01.png}
\end{figure}
% No figure!
\end{document}
```

```
root folder
├main.tex
└───figures
| │ figure01.png
│ │ figure02.png
│ │ figure03.png
└───subfiles
| │ chapter01.tex
| │ chapter02.tex
| │ chapter03.tex
```

The log has the following errors:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.
Use of \m@^_ doesn't match its definition.
Missing number, treated as zero.
Extra \endcsname.
Undefined control sequence.   l.10  \includegraphics{figures/figure.png}
```

Can anyone address me to why it happens and how to fix it?

Output:

[image: compilation output]

Comment: If this is too much trouble to make latex work with hebrew alphabet and if as you suggested (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586500/multi-file-latex-project-with-a-title-page-in-hebrew/) you only need it for the first page, I would suggest to create the first page separately and use `pdfpages` to include it in your document.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this package. Seems correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a clash between the `changepage` package (which is used by `tufte-book`) and the `babel` support for Hebrew, which changes to code for arabic numbers.

It will probably be solved by putting these lines in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\thecp@cntr{\@@arabic\c@cp@cntr}
\makeatother
```

And the `undefined control sequence` can be solved by adding

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Comment: Your suggestion helps to some extent. It solves the first four errors I noted in the original post, but `Undefined control sequence.   l.10  \includegraphics{figures/figure.png}` is still there.

Comment: Actually, when I change the document class from `tufte-book` to `article`, for example, there seems to be no need for the `\def\thecp@cntr{\@@arabic\c@cp@cntr}` command you mentioned, but the "Undefined control sequence" error persists.

Comment: That is right, because it is caused by the `changepage` package and that is not used with the `article` class. And the `undefined control sequence` is probably because you forgot `\usepackage{graphicx}`