# Make Hebrew text less bold on Overleaf

Tags: bold, hebrew

I use Hebrew in Overleaf and for some reason the text always looks really bold compared to English text, which is very annoying. Is there any way this could be fixed?

Code and pic attached. Thanks in advance!

[image: Comparison]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
\begin{document}
הנה קצת טקסט בעברית 
\L{and here's some text in English}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are relying here on babel's default fonts for overleaf's latex distribution. Load and try other fonts and find the one that you like.

Comment: @tush how do you load other fonts and set them as your default?

Comment: Try `\babelfont{rm}[Language=Hebrew]{Font name}` where font name is one of those listed [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Which_OTF_or_TTF_fonts_are_supported_via_fontspec%3F#Fonts_for_Hebrew_script).

Comment: @tush I got this error: 
"l.21 \babelfont
               {rm}[Language=Hebrew]{Arial}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined."

Comment: I'm not sure that using overleaf is a good idea. It seems to have its own idea about LaTeX things.

Comment: @tcb93 You should compile with xelatex not pdflatex.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what fonts are installed in Overleaf, but with

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{nachlieli}
\begin{document}

הנה קצת טקסט בעברית 
\L{and here's some text in English}

\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

Instead of nachlieli, try david, frank, aharoni, drugulin, yad, ellinia, miriam. Choices are quite restricted except if you switch to xetex or luatex, which are supported by `babel`. See, for example:

- [Help getting started with Hebrew in babel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/561139/5735)
- [Getting started with Greek and Hebrew in LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/620541/5735)
- [Minimal Babel and LuaLaTeX Hebrew bidi example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/434568/5735).

An external link is https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/locale-hebrew.html

Answer (score 0):

Try `polyglossia` instead.

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex 

\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
%%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % not needed

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Ligatures=NoCommon]{Linux Libertine O}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}


\begin{document}
    הנה קצת טקסט בעברית 
        
    \L{and here's some text in English} 
    
\end{document}
```