# Bidi patching error in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, hebrew, bidi

Recently I have updated my MikTeX, and eversince I get strange warnings. Based on this [nice example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/354676/135685) I tried to reduce my file to minimal, but I still get these warnings saying `Patching '\begin'` or `\end failed!'`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{SBL Hebrew}[Script=Hebrew]

\begin{document}
Random text.
\begin{hebrew}
בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית
\end{hebrew}
\end{document}
```

What's going on? MikTeX 2.9.7219 portable on Windows 7 64 bit, everything is updated as of yesterday.

Comment: How can I install the update of this package since I have the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [updating](https://github.com/bidi-tex/bidi/issues/10) from version 35.9 to 35.10 the warning disappears and everything works well.

Thank you for the quick patch [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle)!